# How do I figure out if a link is a symbolic link, a hard link, or a directory junction in Windows?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, mklink

If I've created a directory link via mklink, how can I figure out if it was a symbolic link, a directory junction, or a hard link (ie whether I used /d, /j, or /h)?

Comment: You can't create a directory hard link. Apart from that, heavyd's answer is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the command line you can type

```
dir /a
```

You should see something similar to:

```
02/08/2010  11:40 PM    <SYMLINKD>     d1 [..\targetdir1] 
02/08/2010  11:41 PM    <JUNCTION>     d2 [..\targetdir2]
```

This shows a directory symlink (`/D`) and a directory junction (`/J`)

Comment: This need to be in command prompt and NOT in powershell.