# Windows symlink does not show full path?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, mklink, pwd

Current pwd:

```
C:
```

I created a sample symlink say:

```
mklink /j C:\a C:\b\c
```

Thereafter after i navigate using the symlink:

```
cd a
```

If I execute the 'pwd' command, I see the path as **C:\a** Is there a way so that I can see the actual path **C:\b\c**?

Alternatively please point me to the thread if this question has been already answered. I could not locate any relevant answers. Thanks.

Comment: This might answer your question http://superuser.com/questions/106552/how-do-i-figure-out-if-a-link-is-a-symbolic-link-a-hard-link-or-a-directory-ju?rq=1

Comment: No. I don't want to find out about the type of symlink. In Linux, if I navigate to a particular directory using the symlink and then do a `pwd`; I will get the absolute path and not the path referenced by the symlink. I am looking for similar answer on Windows. I hope I am clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to get the behavior you want from that command because it isn't actually making a symlink.  The command `mklink /j` creates what Windows calls Junctions.  They are, for all intents and purposes, an analog to directory hard-links in NTFS.  They also behave differently depending on how you navigate through them (explorer.exe vs. cmd.exe / powershell.exe).

Try using `mklink /d` as this will create a directory symbolic link and may actually provide the functionality you desire.